# Check if email is already registered Firebase REST AUTH API

Tags: java, firebase, rest, firebase-authentication

I am writing a Java program and using a firebase Realtime Database as my database and Firebase Auth as my Auth system. It is not an app so I am interacting with the database and the auth system through their REST API.

My issue is that I can't find a way to check if a user already exists with a given email. There is a different process for signing in vs. signing up. My current solution is to get user input on whether they have signed up before and then use that to navigate the two conditionals. This is fine and works but is not a great UX. Is there a way to use the REST API to check whether an email is already registered on Firebase?

I have seen that there is a way to get user data at the `getAccountInfo` endpoint but this requires an ID which I don't have because they have yet to authenticate. I also saw the getting providers via the `createAuthUri`. This might be what I need but don't understand what this is doing exactly and what URL to provide in the JSON payload string.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you have restricted emails to only be used once by an account (this is turned on/off in the firebase console for the project -> authentication -> sign in methods. Scroll a bit down.), then the `https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signUp?key=[API_KEY]`  endpoint will return an error code of `EMAIL_EXISTS` if the email already exists. More info [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-create-email-password). You can then check if that error message is returned when trying to sign up the user, and then you can call the sign-in endpoint instead.